# Why is this .htaccess rule blocking everyone?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The below seems to be blocking all visitors, yet if i comment out the specific IP the site loads for everyone.

Its added via security however, is blocking everyone out rather than just the specific IP targeted.

I have contacted our hosts and they claim it's nothing to do with them, but surely it's how they have their Apache configured?

```
SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^66\.249\.66\.217$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^66\.249\.66\.217$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^66\.249\.66\.217$" DenyAccess
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Require not env DenyAccess
        Require not ip 66.249.66.217
    </RequireAll>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=DenyAccess
    Deny from 66.249.66.217
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Comment out the specific IP where? Its defined 5 times in this config.

Comment: The `Require not` and `Deny from` lines.

Answer (score 0):

The directives seem to work as is.

To debug this, I would first verify, if `mod_authz_core` is enabled or not.
Based on this, you may check, which of the directives are causing the block, either the environment directive

```
Require not env DenyAccess
Deny from env=DenyAccess
```

or the ip directive

```
Require not ip 66.249.66.217
Deny from 66.249.66.217
```

If the environment is the culprit, check which of the variables is causing it, by commenting one by one.

Comment: Apparently `mod_authz_core ` is enabled the hosting company provided me with the following...
`root@ds60246:/# ll /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ | grep authz_core
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   72 Oct  9  2014 authz_core.load`

Comment: @user4630 Ok, then the `Require` entries are relevant. You can also test for a module, when you put garbage in the appropriate `IfModule` section. At the next request, Apache responds with "500 internal server error".